# Where can I get a list of upcoming features for NXT? and whats on the way for 2014?

Tags: nxt

Where can I get a list of upcoming features for NXT coin? And what are some of the upcoming features for coming 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the NXT-Wiki you can find a list of [planned features](http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Planned_Features) which are currently in development. Here some examples:

- Voting System
- Instant Transactions
- Automated Transactions
- Multisignature transactions
- Shrinking (reduce size of Blockchain)

For a more detailed release plan, I guess you need to check the project sites of specific features.

Comment: @duckx, did that helped you?

Comment: somewhat.. what about the decentralized marketplace? that does what ebay/silk road/craigslist does?